# Arrays in the initialization list of a constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, initialization-list

I'm trying to figure out how to declare an array of an arbitrary size in the constructor's initialization list. If this isn't possible, what should I do instead?

For example:

```
class vectorOfInt
{
public:

private:
    int _size;
    int _vector[];
};

vectorOfInt::vectorOfInt()
    :_size(32),
    _vector(size)
{
}
```

Basically, I want the array _vector to be initialized to size (32 in this case). How do I do that? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

class vectorOfInt
{
public:

private:
    int _size; // probably you want to remove this, use _vector.size() instead.
    std::vector<int> _vector;
};

vectorOfInt::vectorOfInt()
    :_size(32),
    _vector(size)
{
}
```

**Edit**: Since you don't want to use `std::vector`, you'll have to handle memory yourself. You could use a built-in array if you knew the size of the array at compile time, but I doubt this is the case. You'd have to do something like:

```
#include <memory>

class vectorOfInt
{
public:

private:
    int _size;
    // If C++11 is not an option, use a raw pointer.
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> _vector;
};

vectorOfInt::vectorOfInt()
    :_size(32),
    _vector(new int[size])
{
}
```

Comment: and avoid leading underscores (I know it wasn't your idea)

Comment: The point of the exercise is to recreate the vector class in a way that it works just for int

Comment: Are the leading underscores bad style? Is there any other convention for identifying private data fields and methods?

Comment: @BlakeMadden the problem is that they are reserved for implementations, so you could have name clashes that break things at a deep and difficult to figure out. A single trailing underscore is fine.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing. You saved me some typing :-)

Comment: Much appreciated. Side note: is it standard to do initialization in the initialization list or inside the constructor? I know that const types need to be done in the initialization list, but what about others?

Comment: @BlakeMadden you should always use the initialization list whenever possible. Otherwise your class members will be default initialized(using the default constructor), and then again re-initialized in the constructor body. So it's always more efficient to just initialize them once in the init-list.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, `_name` is *not* reserved. `_Name` and `__name` is.

Comment: @Xeo leading underscore (without uppercase) is reserved for implementation names in the global namespace, so I assumed this could cause problems too. Is my reading of §17.4.3.1.2 incorrect? It wouldn't be the first time I misinterpret the standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Aight, in the global namespace it is. As a member however, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use a vector and then use the 'reserve' keyword. This will allocate space for the 32 elements, and you can initialize them to whatever you want.

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class vectorOfInt
{
public:

private:
      int _size;
      vector<int> _vector;

vectorOfInt()
{
    _size = 32;
   _vector.reserve(32);

}



};
```

Comment: I don't think `resize` is what is needed here. One would still have to push_back, and treat the vector as if it were size zero (which it would be).

Comment: It wasn't resize. It's 'reserve'. You can push_back for these 32 elements after space has been allocated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `reserve`. `resize` would be fine, but then you might as well use the size constructor.